# The puma server freezes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, puma

I can not understand what the problem is. The app works perfectly after I start it. After a while of inactivity (around 5 min with no requests) the app stops responding when I send requests to it.

puma.rb:

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }.to_i
threads threads_count, threads_count

port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

plugin :tmp_restart
```

This is what I get when I do this: `ps aux | grep puma`

> user+  4201  7.8  2.5 1197292 100560 ?      Sl   15:41   0:04 puma 3.11.4 (tcp://0.0.0.0:3000) [backend]
>
> user+  4277  0.0  0.0  15476  1020 pts/20   S+   15:42   0:00 grep --color=auto puma

```
ruby -v
```

> ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-linux]

```
rails -v
```

> Rails 5.1.6

OS Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Just to clarify, is this in a development environment? Also, may be handy to know which OS & Ruby/Rails versions you are using.

Comment: @ThorTL67 yes, Versions of the OS, etc. Added to the question

Comment: I had to go to the  server "passenger"

Answer (score 0):

this is what your `puma.rb` should look like

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```